# How to get the currently chose build variant in gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Android Studio RC with gradle 2.2. I have in my build variants section a few variants and I can choose which one I want to build. For example one build for Hungary or for Germany.

I have a few tasks that I launch in my gradle script like changing the name based on the flavor/variant. But at the moment the script iterates over all the build variants like so:
`android.applicationVariants.each { variant ->`.

So my question is: how can I get only the chosen variant from the android studio `Build Variants` section and use it in gradle script, so to remove the loop?

Comment: I don't think you can. Why do you want to remove the loop?

Comment: well, it loops over all the build variants, while I want to use only one

Comment: Looping over all build variants doesn't mean you'll use more than one. Perhaps you can improve your question and explain in detail which bigger problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply check the variant name and only run certain tasks for specific flavors, like this:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.name.contains('myflavor')) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Just put it in your build.gradle file for the app. Outside of the android {} block. It will then run during every build.

Comment: There is no (simple) way to get the variant for the build that is running. The OP wants to customize the build based on the variant, and the best way to do that, is by using this loop.